# redirect to next location doesnt work

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
require 'Config.php';

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try {
      $Name = $_POST['Name'];
      $Password = $_POST['Password'];
      $message ="";

      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE Name='$Name' and Password='$Password'");
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->fetchcolumn();

         if($result == 0) {
           echo $result;
           echo "Invalid Username or Password";
         }
         elseif($result >= 1) {
           echo $result;
           $_SESSION['Name']=$result['Name'];
           header('Location: ../Holiday_Planer/Login-Success.php');
           exit();
     }
   }
   catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
   }
   $conn = null;
  }
?>
```

the script runs then goes to the next page and i get an error 404 the file is definitely in the location so not sure why this is not working please help

Comment: header location should be an absolute URL path (like: `/path-from-doc-root-to/Holiday_Planer/Login-Success.php`), not a relative file path

Comment: Could you illustrate your directory structure - i.e. what file the given code is in and where the target file is?

Comment: its the actual header its self as i have commented it out and the script runs fine and returns a value

Answer (score 0):

header('Location: ../Holiday_Planer/Login-Success.php') should work in most cases.
You can try header('url: ../Holiday_Planer/Login-Success.php'); if it doesn't.

Comment: i have tired both of these ways and everytime just comes back with error 404